# Adding a UIBezierPath in to cell.contentview in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uicollectionview, uibezierpath

I want to add a slide shape to the cell content view in uicollectionview in iOS.I am doing like this in

> collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
 UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(cell.frame.size.width-15, 0.0)];

    // Draw the lines.
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];

    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(15, cell.frame.size.height)];

    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

    [aPath closePath];


    [self setClippingPath:aPath :cell];
```

and i am adding path in this method to cell like this

```
- (void)setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath : (id )imgView;
    {
        if (![[imgView layer] mask])
            [[imgView layer] setMask:[CAShapeLayer layer]];


        [(CAShapeLayer*) [[imgView layer] mask] setPath:[clippingPath CGPath]];


    }
```

But it is adding in different width in each time.the spacing between the cells are changing on each reload in the collection view.I am also adding linespacing to -13 to get the slide correctly between the cells like

```
`- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{

    return -13.0;


}`
```

Can anybody knows why the spacing between the cells are going different on each time ?